# The CancellationTokenSource has been disposed during messaging

Tags: c#, firebase, blazor, blazor-server-side

I work with the built-in messaging system in the project, based on the Server Side Blazor, using SQL Server and Firebase. Messages are sent and received via SQL Server, and real-time message delivery is via Firebase.

After selecting a thread, client make subscribe to messages and the status of the interlocutor in Firebase. These operations take a time, so I display the interface and perform them in the background. The problem is that a user can switch to another thread before all subscriptions to the previous one occur.

To handle this, I tried using the following code:

```
@code { 
    private bool _processing = true;           
    private CancellationTokenSource _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();   
    private CancellationToken? _token;     
    private Task? _slowOperations;          

    private async Task GetMessagesAsync()     
    {     
        _processing = true;     
        // SQL Server operations     
        _processing = false;             
        StateHasChanged(); 

        if (_slowOperations != null && !slowOperations.IsCompletedSuccessfully)      
        {     
            _cts.Cancel();             
            _cts.Dispose();             
            _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();     
            _token = _cts.Token;     
        }             

        _slowOperations = Task.Run(() => ProceedSlowOperations(_token!.Value));             
    } 
         
    private async Task ProceedSlowOperations (CancellationToken cancellationToken)     
    {     
        await Task.Delay(5000);     

        if (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)     
        {     
            // make firebase subscriptions.     
        }             
 }
```

Thus, if the user switched between threads several times, subscriptions will be issued only 5 seconds after the last switch. Previous calls will be reset. But when using such code, at some intervals of switching between threads, the error appears “The CancellationTokenSource has been disposed.” Even if I remove all occurrences of "_cts.Dispose()" the error continues to occur. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the Blazor component itself getting destroyed because the user navigates away?

Comment: No, the user do not navigates away, just changing thread too quickly

Answer (score 0):

The error was not related to _token. It appeared when executing

```
_threadSubscription.Dispose();
```

despite the fact that CancellationToken was not explicitly used there. We managed to get around the problem using the construction

```
try
{
_threadSubscription.Dispose();
}
catch (ObjectDisposedException e){

}
```